# Travelling multiple EU countries from SG, dual citizenship BG / TR, different names

Tags: dual-nationality, eu-citizens

I have Bulgaria-Turkey dual citizenship with different names (not even a word is matching in surname or name, totally different, only birthdays are matching in two passports basically). I do live in Singapore (I have a residency visa w my Turkish passport & name). I have a coming trip to Europe, and we will be visiting Germany, France and Portugal, for about 2 weeks. 
Since I have Bulgarian passport (EU citizen), I have freedom of travel in EU countries.

My questions are:
1. Under which name I should book my tickets? Or should I book w different names for internal EU layover flights? Or it doesn't matter?

My plan is initially:

1. Book ticket w (home country (SG)), Turkish passport (since I have SG residency).
2. Airline check-in, show them my Bulgarian passport (EU).
3. At Immigration, show Turkish (TR) passport w Residency when leave.
4. Arrive Germany, show BG passport at immigration.
5. Flying to France, at check-in,  show Bulgarian passport (but for name mismatch, I show TR passport, or I book my ticket with BG passport for internal EU flights is better?)
6. At immigration, show BG passport (my worry is at immigration if they wanna check my ticket & BG passport, they will see mismatch names, and I need to explain them dual citizenship).
7. Arrive France, show BG passport at immigration.
8. Flying to Portugal, at check-in, show BG passport (again for name mismatch, I show TR passport, or I book my ticket w BG passport for internal EU flights? basically the same thing as #5)
9. At immigration, show BG passport (Again, same concerns as #6, and may need to explain them dual citizenship).
10. Arrive Portugal, show BG passport at immigration.
11. Flying back to SG, at check-in, show TR passport since i have a residency visa. (this time name is matching)
12. At immigration show BG passport (Again, same concerns as #6, ticket and name in BG passport not matching)
13. Arrive SG, show TR passport at immigration.

Please let me know if my plan sounds correct.

In summary,

1. A) should I follow same name booking ( in this case home country (SG) w TR
   passport) for all flights?
2. B) or should I book EU flights w BG passport separately?
3. C) or should I just book all flights w BG passport since they are the majority of flights in this case?

Besides above questions, If you have any other suggestions, I would like to hear them as well.
Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: Use the same name on the tickets as the passport you're planning to show the airlines.  Immigration usually doesn't care about your flight ticket.

Comment: I agree with @jpatokal, but maybe you should show also the other passport to airline (they will often check for visa). How different are the names? [If just transliterated, translated, simplified, similar sound or new surname because marriage, it is not a problem, they can relate the two persons].

Comment: They are totally different name and surname, not even a word is matching. Only birthday is matching in two passports basically. Difference from other question mentioned is this travel is involving from non-home country travelling to another and multiple destinations  and returning back to non-home country again.